# 2 binary strings. The function will multiply these two arguments and return the result as a binary string

Tags: javascript, binary, binary-string

> And Write a JS function that takes 2 arguments: 2 binary strings. The
>   function will multiply these 
>          two arguments and return the result as a binary string.
>
> ```
>     Note_: A binary string is a sequence of bytes, such as `"1001001100"`
>    input= ("01011001010101", "11011111010101"),
>      output= 100110111101101011110111001
> ```

```
For Example :   
str1 = `"10"`  
str2 = `"100"`  
Output = `"1000"`


 '''
    function raj(n1,n2){
    var n1=n1.split("")
    var n2=n2.split("")
    var mul=[]
    for(var i=0;i<n1.length;i++){
     for(var ;j<n2.length;j--){
      var k=n1[i]*n2[j]
     mul.push(k)
     }
    }
     return mul
    }
    var x=raj("10","100")
    console.log(x)
  '''
```

Comment: You posted an assignment and some code. What is the problem or question?

Comment: Actually i i want to multiply two binary string like if is multiply without converting into string because when i convert it in the integer then multiply and again convert it into binary the output is different ..please help me out

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that multiplies two binary strings and returns the output as a binary string:

```
function multiplyBinaryStrings (binaryString1, binaryString2){
    let int1 = parseInt(binaryString1, 2)
    let int2 = parseInt(binaryString2, 2)
    return (int1 * int2).toString(2)
}
```

Comment: when we run this code the output is 1.0011011110110101e+26 for the input "01011001010101","11011111010101" .... we just multiply these two string without converting into binary this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) in js

```
var output = (BigInt(parseInt("01011001010101",2)) * BigInt(parseInt("11011111010101",2))).toString(2);
// --> 100110111101101011110111001
```

Comment: Good answer, but please update the link to point to the English docs.